# I want to insert object with container list

Tags: c++, list, containers

I want to add contact on some index and i can't figure it out why is this code not working.

I have problem with this line:

```
a = (*it);
```

and this one:

```
tmp.push_back(listOf[a]);
```

This is the code:

```
void insert(list<Contact> &listOf, int index, const Contact &info) {

    list<Contact> tmp;
    int a;
    for(list<Contact>::iterator it = listOf.begin(); it != listOf.end(); it++)
    {
        a = (*it);
        if(a == index)
        {
            tmp.push_back(info);
            index -= 2;
            it--;
        }
        else
            tmp.push_back(listOf[a]);
    }
    listOf = tmp;
}
```

I have structure Contact with name and surname (string).

Maybe is something wrong with just those two lines? Or is it entire code wrong? If it is, i would be glad if someone can get me a solution.

Comment: `*it` is Contact type, it's not `int`

Comment: `(*it);`yields a `Contact` not an `int`. To have an index use a separate counter.

Comment: you may want to use std::vector instead of std::list in your program. This would make your life much easy as you want to do something with index in the container.

Comment: I have to make program with list

Comment: first comment says it all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you expect that a list is the same as a vector, and can be used interchangeably.

First of all when you dereference an iterator, it returns the the type of the container, in your case an instance of `Contact`. Secondly, you can't use array-like indexing on a `std::list`.

To solve the first problem, you have to keep track of indexes yourself.

To solve the second problem, you already have the iterator and can use that in the `push_back` call:

```
tmp.push_back(*it);
```

Comment: It solve my problem but now I got one new one in this line if(a==index). I get this error: no match for 'operator==' in 'a == index'

Comment: @user3127680 Then I guess you changed `a` to be a `Contact`. You still need it to be an integer, initialized to zero and increased in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that class (or structure) Contact has no conversion function that converts an object of type Contact to an object of type int. So this code is invalid

```
int a;
//,,,
    a = (*it);
```

because the type of expression `*it` is `Contact` not int.

Also class `std::list` has no subscript operator. So this statement

```
tmp.push_back(listOf[a]);
```

is also invalid and the compiler shall issue an error.

Comment: It solve my problem but now I got one new one in this line if(a==index). I get this error: no match for 'operator==' in 'a == index'

Comment: @user3127680 If a has no type int and for example has type Contact then there is no operator == for objects of these types. What is the type of a?

Comment: It's type Contact. How can I check now where to insert if they are not same type?

Comment: @user3127680 I think you need not compare the whole structure with an integer but only some data member of the structure with this integer. For example if ( a.SomeDataMember == index )